# find duplicate files by their prefix (not hash)

Tags: linux

If I have 2 files where one is:

```
2020-07-03-21_56_51-a.jpg
```

the other one:

```
2020-07-03-21_56_51-b.jpg
```

and those are the same files where for example `fdupes .` doesn't recognize them as duplicates.

**How do I match the timedate format and print them out as possible duplicates?**

Comment: What do you mean by "same files"? Are their contents the same? Or you just want to match them by the timestamp regardless of their contents?

Comment: @choroba files are slightly different which means that I can't compare their hashes. What I want is to print those 2 file names because the prefix (everything up to `-a`, `-b` is the same )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @BryanK although I agree that there should be at least "minimal reproducible example" I think I explained well what I need in my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time format you showed forms a 19 character long prefix on a file name. If we assume that you do not require to handling of other prefixes, then you can pipe the list of such files to the following perl script like `ls *.jpg | perl first19match.pl`.

Save the following code in file named `first19match.pl`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# group files by PREFIX

my @in = <>;

my %o;

for (@in) {
    my $p = substr $_, 0, 19;    #the PREFIX extractor
    $o{$p} = [] unless exists $o{$p};
    push @{ $o{$p} }, $_;
}

print
  map { ( "possible duplicates:\n", @{ $o{$_} }, "\n" ) if ( @{ $o{$_} } > 1 ) }
  keys %o;
```

The program prints each group of files with same prefix in a different paragraph. For the input:

```
2020-07-03-21_56_51-a.jpg
2020-07-03-21_56_51-b.jpg
2020-07-03-21_50_34-fhv.asd
2020-07-03-21_50_34-cubj.tgg
```

the output is:

```
possible duplicates:
2020-07-03-21_56_51-a.jpg
2020-07-03-21_56_51-b.jpg

possible duplicates:
2020-07-03-21_50_34-fhv.asd
2020-07-03-21_50_34-cubj.tgg
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try a perl oneliner that pushs the list of files into a hash list based on the timestamp before the "_" in the file name

```
ls 2020* | perl -F"_" -lane 'push @{$list{$F[0]}}, $_; END { foreach $k (keys %list) { print join ",", "duplicates?", @{$list{$k}} } }'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the a-files and search for the corresponding b-files:

```
#! /bin/bash
for filea in ????-??-??-??_??_??-a.jpg ; do
    fileb=${filea%-a.jpg}-b.jpg
    if [[ -f $fileb ]] ; then
        echo Found "$filea" "$fileb"
    else
        echo Not found the b file for "$filea"
    fi
done
```

You can also use `comm` to process the lists of a-files and b-files. The b-files are changed to look like a-files, so comm reports the output in three columns: 1. b-file not found, 2. a-file not found, 3. both files exist.

```
comm <(ls ????-??-??-??_??_??-a.jpg) \
     <(ls ????-??-??-??_??_??-b.jpg | sed 's/-b\.jpg/-a.jpg/')
```

Comment: I am getting not found with above bash script although there are -a and -b files. Shouldn't the is else statements be reversed?

Comment: It works for me. I originally had a typo in the script, check you have the latest version.

Comment: still getting not found with these 2 files in folder ls -> `2020-07-03-21_56_51-a.jpg  2020-07-03-21_56_52-b.jpg`  -> `not found
Not found the b file for 2020-07-03-21_56_51-a.jpg`

Comment: Yes, that's expected, 51 != 52.

Comment: you are right, I made mistake when I tried to reproduce my first attempt. But I tried i again now and multiple times before and I am still getting `not found`